# How can I parse the artifactory trigger output in a pipeline script?

Tags: build, triggers, artifactory

I have a requirement where I need to parse the artifactory path in the console output which triggered the build in a pipeline script.
How do I access the path? Is there an environment variable which stores this info or how can I access the console log to parse it if not.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently impossible in non-hacky ways to retrieve the path.

However, I created this [PR](https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/pull/356) to fulfill your request. I will let you know once this PR is merged and the next plugin version is released.
You can also watch this [Jira ticket](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1246).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Jenkins Artifactory plugin 3.9.0 is released. On this version, the URL of the build cause is exposed to be accessed by pipelines. You can access the path as following:

```
echo "Build caused by a change in ${currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].url}"
```